# Right-align text in a TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have some RTL text (Hebrew) that I want to be aligned right inside the TextView. Currently the XML looks like this:

```
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textDirection="rtl"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

And it acually works great on Galaxy S3 Android 4.2.2 and I even tested it on a Galaxy S1 Android 2.3.3 and it was ok too. But on some devices, for example Galaxy S2 Android 2.3.5, it's aligned left for some reason.

I searched alot and I did not find and solution to this problem, I'd be happy if someone will show me a solution within the XML layout file, but programatcly solution can work as well.

Comment: Try to remove `android:singleLine="false"`

Answer (score 1):

I tired with your code.. you want to placed the text in right  side of textview right?...
I'm pretty to help you because, I also gone through this issue..

In your code,

```
android:gravity="right"
```

Instead of this, try this

```
 android:gravity="end"
```

I think this is what you are looking for

Comment: @Untrade... Is it okey for your issue

Comment: I have yet to try this solution, i'll post here the comment with the result soon.

Comment: Yeah, waiting for your solution, @UnTraDe